# Which scenario can detach a static external IP from a VM in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-vpc, hyper-virtualization

I created a static IP in VPC network and attached it to a VM as the external IP address.

[image]

However, two weeks after the assignment of the static IP to the VM, I noticed that the static IP was automatically detached from the VM and I had to attached the IP there again.

What are the circumstances which lead to such a detachment If my VMs are of standard machine types? Can Kubernetes upgrade do this?

Comment: Is the VM part of a GKE cluster? If so, it seems reasonable that this can happen. If a VM is managed for you by GCP (like a GKE cluster node), then when it performs management operations on those nodes there's no guarantee that manual changes you make to the VM are carried forward. There may be different ways to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to accomplish that doesn't require you to manually associate an external IP to a node.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Do you know how I should assign an external IP to a node in GKE? In my understanding, external IP is an external resource for GKE. So, would it be able to deal with such a resource?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have a microservice which accesses an API which white lists incoming IPs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can assign static IPs to nodes in a GKE cluster, these will be automatically detached if the node gets recreated (either, by autoscaling or node repair).

In theory, Kubernetes/GKE are systems with dynamic resources, not supposed to preserve [state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)) (in most cases). If you want to add a static way to access the cluster, rather use [Load Balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#loadbalancer) or [Ingress objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

In the scenario where you need to have a unified outbound address, you can use [GKE with Cloud NAT](https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-cloud-nat-with-gke-cluster-c82364546d9e) to "unify" the dynamic node IPs for outbound connections.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm going to try this.